# getting output of command in subprocess

Tags: python, output, popen

I saw a few threads for this, but everything there didn't help me.

I'm running a subprocess to run commands on cmd via python(using 2.7)

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["start",  "cmd", "/k", command], shell=True)
```

This command works and everything, but I can't manage to capture the output of the command.

I tried `check_output` or specifying `stdout=sp.PIPE` or `stdout=file`, but it didn't work.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_output` should work fine:

```
from subprocess import check_output

out = check_output(["echo", "Test"], shell=True)
```

Output of command:

```
>>> print out
Test
```

Comment: Be careful with `shell=True` though. It can be a security risk (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Comment: is there a difference between `sp.check_output(["ipconfig"], shell=True)` and `sp.Popen(["start",  "cmd", "/k", "ipconfig"], shell=True)`?

Comment: from what i can see option 1 doesn't open cmd, but executes it in python. and option 2 opens it in cmd. but they run the same command

Comment: The `shell=True` is completely useless here anyway; even if you don't care about security, the additional overhead and hidden complexity should scare you.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: `Popen()` merely *starts* the process.  For a simple process, that may be enough to get you the output, but you should understand that you are responsible for managing the process and cleaning up when it is done.  The various `subprocess` wrappers take care of this for you.  Eventually they all call `Popen` but you should avoid that unless you have complex needs.

Comment: I meant as a cmd command. is there any difference? because option 2 opens a cmd window and runs the command there, option 1 runs a cmd command on python

Comment: It doesn't run "on python" but certainly as a subprocess of Python.  If you wanted to ask about the difference between `cmd` and no `cmd`, why does one have `check_output` and the other `Popen`?  Those are quite different.  In the meantime, sure, you can wrap arbitrary levels of external tools, or, say, `python -c 'os.system("python -c \"os.system(\"\"python ...` and eventually produce the same end result, but why would you?

Comment: @tripleee Yes `shell=True` is useless, but for my specific example it was required.

Comment: On Windows that is, I know it's different on Linux